# why can I not run a file from sublime text?

Tags: file, sublimetext3

I recently installed sublime text and could run files without any problem. I configured sublime to use the correct python version.

A few days later I reinstalled Anaconda on my computer. Now, I cannot run the files from sublime text anymore. There is the following error:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python3'

I am confused. In my Terminal I have python version 3.8. Is it because Anaconda has only version 3.7?

Thanks for your help, I am stuck.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python3'
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '/Users/andreamathis/Desktop/pythonCrashCourse/ch2/name.py']]
[dir: /Users/andreamathis/Desktop/pythonCrashCourse/ch2]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

Comment: For this to work, there has to be a program named `python3` in one of the four paths listened in the `[path:` part of the error diagnostic. You should be able to go into a Terminal and type `which python3` and have it give you a result that matches one of those folders. If not, you need to set up your system so the operating system knows where to find the Python interpreter when Sublime asks it to run it. Presumably the reinstalls you did removed a version of Python that used to exist but now no longer does.